# Use R to edit columns in Excel using data from two Excel documents

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I need to correct the time/date of a series of data collection sessions which all correspond to the same deployment ID in excel spreadsheet 1 (multiple lines with the same deployment ID). The corrections are stored in excel spreadsheet 2, with each deployment ID taking up one line of data. There are 315 deployment IDs.

How can I do this using R?

I think I need a statement to the extent of

```
 for (i in 1:315){
    if (doc1$deploymentID==i)
    doc1$time=doc2$time[i]
    }
```

I could use some help so I don't make a huge mess of my data.

Comment: You don't need a loop for this.  If the deploymentIDs are the same in both and in the same order, just do `doc1$time <- doc2$time` (assuming that you already read the excel sheets i.e. (check `?read.csv`) and doc1 and doc2 are the object names).

Comment: Or `merge(doc1, doc2, by="deploymentID")`. The best way to get help is to create an example with a sample of the data you're working with.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful start. Instead of just merging the data I need to use a time element from doc2 to correct those in doc1. For example, within one deployment 80 observations were made. Since the camera recording observations had the incorrect time set, all times are behind by 2 days and 4 hours. Doc2 has a column which has this "2 days 4 hours" correction factor. I need to add "2 days 4 hours" to each of the 80 lines of data so I have the correct times.